# How to set .NET Client webservice ClientRuntime.MaxFaultSize

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I'm calling a java webservice that returns a type of FaultException that contains a list of errors. So the response message size is always large.

In my c# (clr3.5) client I get the following error

***"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."***

I believe the fix for this is to set the `ClientRuntime.MaxFaultSize` [msdn-doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.clientruntime.maxfaultsize.aspx)

Is there a way to do this in the app.config ?

Answer (score 6):

You must set ClientRuntime.MaxFaultSize property, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.clientruntime.maxfaultsize.aspx)

1. Create your MaxFaultSizeBehaviour

```
public class MaxFaultSizeBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
 private int _size;

 public MaxFaultSizeBehavior(int size)
 {
  _size = size;
 }

 public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
 {
 }

 public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
 {
  clientRuntime.MaxFaultSize = _size;
 }

 public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
 {
 }

 public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
 {
 }
}
```

1. Apply created behaviour at client size:

a) to ChannelFactory:

```
ChannelFactory channelFactory = new ChannelFactory(binding, endPointAddress);
channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MaxFaultSizeBehavior(500000));
```

b) or to generated proxy:

```
proxy.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SetMaxFaultSizeBehavior(500000));
```

Comment: The question clearly asked how to do this in an app.config scenario as a lot of WCF configuration would have been configured that way and not in code as your example suggests?

Comment: @MikeTours Doing this in config is not supported, as per the following MSDN link, thus doing it in code seems to be the only option. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2716f93f-bb91-4366-a14e-4a4121a74df6/configuring-maximum-fault-size

Answer (score 1):

When we ran into this problem, we followed the error message and changed the MaxReceivedMessageSize property in the bindings configuration of our app.config.  Is this not working for you?

```
   maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"  <!-- Change this -->

      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
```

EDIT: If that still doesn't work, I found [this post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/08/07/wcf-client-fault-size-limit.aspx).  It suggests creating a Contract Behavior attribute.  While the example codes the limit into the attribute constructor, you could pull from your own configuration value.  Haven't seen a straight .NET configuration yet, but I'd look in behavior configuration.

Comment: Was that for faults? It is, or was, different for fault data: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/08/07/increasing-the-maximum-fault-size.aspx

Comment: Must not have been for faults, sorry about that.  I did find one example for faults that I linked to in the edit:.  I'll browser through the behavior configuration as well to see if there's anything there.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I ended up at the same post.  Looks like you need to create a custom behavior for that one.  Sorry about that.

Comment: maxReceivedMessageSize won't work for faults, a custom behavior is what I'm looking for, anyone got  decent example of one for the app/web config?

Comment: Doing this in config is not supported.